# How can I count EC2 instances over time in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, performance-monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to know the number of EC2 instances I have running over time. I am able to view this data from the following menu:

- ec2 dashboard

  - `Auto Scaling Groups`

    - select my group from the table of groups

      - select `monitoring` tab

        - select graph of `Total Instances ( Count )`

the url for this view should look something like this

https://`<region>`.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/home?region=`<region>`#AutoScalingGroups:id=`<my-id>`;view=monitoring;SH_S=Successful

(specific information to my application replaced with `<text>`)

---

However, if I wanted to replicate this query in AWS CloudWatch, I do not know what search term to use in the query language. The default query provided when I attempt to generate a graph is

```
SEARCH('{AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName="CPUUtilization"', 'Average', 300)
```

When I search [the documentation for "Available CloudWatch Metrics for Your Instances"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html) I do not see any metric that will let me determine the number of running instances at a given time. I found the `SampleCount` term; however, this is the count of data points sampled for the statistic.